# Save an editable long text from a UITextView

Tags: ios, textview, save

I am building an iPad app, where the user can type a long text on a `textView`,
this text is going to get saved, for later retrieval.

So what is the best approach to save this long "string"
if I want to save a document with more than 10 pages...

is CoreData ok?

or should i use plists? or save it to a txt file?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clarifications on the question:

- "10 pages" - is that about 20 kbytes more or less?
- When you describe "saving for later retrieval", does "later" mean in a subsequent invocation of the app?
- There are some subtle considerations related to data longevity - e.g., do you wish the saved text to persist across upgrades to your app, or be cleared out with installation of a new version?

Files are a good place to save data between executions of an app - even in iOS.  So, yes a file (txt or other suitable type) is a great first choice.  Do be careful what directory in which you place it (check out `NSDocumentDirectory`), consider using a dedicated subdirectory, and think about what circumstances you want to remove or clear it out.

There's no great advantage to putting long text strings into a plist, but if you have other associated data (author name, date entered, revision history, etc.) a plist can add useful structure.  And plists are easily loaded into dictionaries or other similar structures.  (Also, check out `NSUserDefaults` for useful plist capabilities.)

CoreData is awesome, but may be overkill for what you described.

I'd recommend the options you mentioned, but in reverse order:

- save to a file
- if you want more structure, save as a plist
- if you want even more structure and features, save with CoreData

Good luck!